# Variable capturing mod_rewrite

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, web-applications, mod-rewrite

Basically, I've been arranging multiple redirects at work for site migration. However, at my work we have multiple servers for testing/development/production. The domains are usually mapped as follows:

`http://<accountname>.(test|dev|).<maindomain>.edu.au`

For internal redirects there's no issues with maintaining references to the appropriate server. However, when we perform a migration to another account on the site, it becomes a bit more difficult to ensure that the redirect stays on the appropriate server.

For example, say we've decided to redirect the "foo" account to "bar" for my company named "foobar".

```
Foo's production URL:  http://foo.foobar.edu.au
Foo's test URL:        http://foo.test.foobar.edu.au
Foo's development URL: http://foo.dev.foobar.edu.au

Bar's production URL:  http://bar.foobar.edu.au
Bar's test URL:        http://bar.test.foobar.edu.au
Bar's development URL: http://bar.dev.foobar.edu.au
```

Basically I need to write the htaccess file such that all requests to `foo` are mapped appropriately to `bar`'s `test/dev/production` domains.

The way I've achieved this at the moment is to use a RewriteCond and capture some of the server info for the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^foo(\.test|\.dev|\.)foobar.edu.au
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bar%1foobar.edu.au/$1
```

Which works fine for bulk redirects. However, when I need to get slightly more fancy (i.e not all of `foo`'s directories match the exact same path on `bar` and require individual redirects), I find that I need copy the same `RewriteCond` for each new `RewriteRule` (because you can't apply a `RewriteCond` to multiple `RewriteRule`'s while still capturing data.

For example:

```
# resources/data has been duplicated on bar
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^foo(\.test\.|\.dev\.|\.)foobar.edu.au
    RewriteRule ^(resources/data/.+)$ http://bar%1foobar.edu.au/$1 [R=301,L]
# the rest of foo just points to a static page on bar
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^foo(\.test\.|\.dev\.|\.)foobar.edu.au
    RewriteRule ^ http://bar%1foobar.edu.au/migration/foo.cfm [R=301,L]
# there are actually more, but removed for brevity
```

**TL;DR**
Is there a straightforward way to capture a section of the **`SERVER_PATH`** variable and use it throughout multiple `RewriteRule`'s?

I'm quite a novice with mod_rewrite so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a straightforward way to capture a section of the SERVER_PATH variable and use it throughout multiple RewriteRule's?

I don't think there's a way aside from duplicating the match and using a backreference each time you need to use it. However, could this be a little easier if you handed it off to a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)?

Maybe something like (this would have to be in your vhost or server config):

```
RewriteMap mymap prg:/path/to/my/mapping/script.sh
```

Then in your htaccess you can invoke it like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${mymap:%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}|$1} [L]
```

So your script.sh would need to take a `%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}` (which theoretically would be something like: `foo.test.foobar.edu.au/some/path/to/file.html`) and figure out where it needs to go. If you need to redirect a browser, output a result that starts with `http://` otherwise it would internally rewrite.

Comment: I would like to avoid using any shell scripts. This is an enterprise network and I'm just a humble web-developer on it. It's quite frowned upon to start modifying configurations etc. If needs be I can just suck it up and copy/paste the RewriteCond a couple of times. The old domain is being migrated anyway, so I probably won't have to look at the htaccess again.

Comment: @JasonLarke Sorry, forgot to mention you could just have a mapping file instead of a shell script. I had provided a link to the RewriteMap docs which gives you a list of the kinds of maps it'll take. The simplest being a "[A plain text file containing space-separated key-value pairs, one per line](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt)". But I don't know if that's going to be any easier

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks. My bad, didn't click the link. I'll look into that now and get back to you.

Comment: Seems pretty useless for my case where I still need to utilize RegEx in some of the cases. As far as I can tell from what I've read, unless I write a custom program to transform the query (i.e Py/Perl..etc), which isn't viable, there's no way to support RegEx in RewriteMap.